# What's a shorter way to say recommendation?

Tags: vocabulary, abbreviations

Looking for abbreviation or similar meaning words.

The context is recommended songs, movies, books etc.

I need a shorter way to say the same thing (preferably half the characters) in order to fit it into a mobile application user interface.

I checked Thesaurus but doesn't help.

Comment: Could you give an example sentence where you want to use the shorter word?

Comment: I'm guessing the fact that you "need" a shorter word implies it's for a software User Interface context. In which case it might be that ***rating*** (as in 1-5 stars) would work best.

Comment: The word "commend" is almost half the length of recommendation, and it's similar enough in meaning to substitute for it.  E.g., "I commend this movie to you," or "I commend this book to you for your reading pleasure." Since we're in the era of LOL, you could also use "TU" for thumbs up, and "TD" for thumbs down.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context, but how about "tip"?